Need help to resolve an issue in Example 10.8 (2) of Representations And Characters Of Groups
This question comes from the book Representations And Characters Of Groups by James & Liebeck. In Chapter 10, Example 10.8 (2) deals with $\mathbb C[D_6]$, where $D_6$ is the dihedral group of $6$ elements generated by $a$ and the involution $b$. There are six quantities
\begin{align*}
    v_0 &= 1 + a + a^2, &w_0 &=bv_0, \\
    v_1 &= 1 + \omega^2 a + \omega a^2, &w_1 &=bv_1, \\
    v_2 &= 1 + \omega a + \omega^2 a^2, &w_2 &=bv_2,
\end{align*}
where $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$. These define four $\mathbb C$-subspaces
\begin{align*}
    U_1 &=\langle v_0+w_0\rangle  &U_3 &= \langle v_1,w_2\rangle\\
    U_2 &=\langle v_0-w_0\rangle  &U_4 &= \langle v_2,w_1\rangle.
\end{align*}
The goal is to show that
$$
  \mathbb C[D_6] = U_1\oplus U_2\oplus (U_3\oplus U_4)
$$
as a sum of (bilateral) ideals, where $U_3\cong U_4$. The book says that one can take the isomorphism defined by $v_1\mapsto w_1$, $w_2\mapsto v_2$. However, if $\phi$ is such a map, then
$$
  \phi(av_1) = \phi(\omega v_1) = \omega\phi(v_1) = \omega w_1
$$
while
$$
  a\phi(v_1) = aw_1 = abv_1 = ba^2v_1 = b\omega^2v_1 = \omega^2w_1,
$$
and so $\phi(av_1)\ne a\phi(v_1)$. Since it can be proved that $U_3\subseteq I\Rightarrow U_4\subseteq I$ for every ideal $I$, we get an indirect proof that $U_3$ and $U_4$ must be isomorphic. My question is: what explicitly defined map realizes the isomorphism?

I think you are forgetting that James and Liebeck act on the right, so that the homomorphism condition is $(v_1 a) \phi = (v_1)\phi a$

@MatthewTowers You are right (no pun intended). Do you have a suggestion on how to define a left-acting isomorphism (which my argument shows that must exist). In any case, if you move your comment to an answer I'll accept it. Thank you.

I don't want to work the details, but inverting every group element will have the effect of swapping left and right, so you only need to keep track of the effect on the $v_i$ and $w_i$ (e.g. $v_1$ becomes $v_2$, \ldots).
